# Complex Integration General problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Having a bit of trouble how to deal with this question:

Let $f=u+iv$ and $\gamma(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$ be a piecewise smooth curve.

Show: $$Re[\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz] = \int_\gamma(udx-vdy)$$

and

$$Im[\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz] = \int_\gamma(vdx+udy)$$

Here
$dx = x'(t)dt$ and $dy = y'(t)dt$

Not sure how to even start. Guessing I use the definition of a line integral but not sure what taking the real or imaginary part of the integrals does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gamma $ is defined on $[a,b]$ then $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz =\int_a^{b} (u(\gamma(t))+iv(\gamma(t))(x'(t)+i(v'(t))dt$. So the real part is $\int_a^{b} \Re[(u(\gamma(t))+iv(\gamma(t))(x'(t)+i(v'(t))]dt$ which is $\int_a^{b} [u(\gamma(t)x'(t)-v(\gamma(t))v'(t)]dt$. This is same as $\int_{\gamma} (udx-vdy)$. Imaginary part is similar.